# Excel/VBA/Conditional Formatting: Dictionary of Dictionaries

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting, array-formulas

I've got an Excel workbook that obtains data from an MS SQL database. One of the sheets is used to check the data against requirements and to highlight faults. In order to do that, I've got a requirements sheet where the requirement is in a named range; after updating the data I copy the conditional formatting of the table header to all data rows. That works pretty nicely so far. The problem comes when I have more than one set of requirements:

An (agreeably silly) example could be car racing, where requirements may exist for driver's license and min/max horsepower. When looking at the example, please imagine there are a few thousand rows and 71 columns presently...

```
+-----+--------+----------------+------------+---------+
| Car |  Race  | RequirementSet | Horsepower | License |
+-----+--------+----------------+------------+---------+
|  1  | Monaco |        2       |     200    |    A    |
+-----+--------+----------------+------------+---------+
|  2  | Monaco |        2       |     400    |    B    |
+-----+--------+----------------+------------+---------+
|  3  |  Japan |        3       |     200    |    C    |
+-----+--------+----------------+------------+---------+
|  4  |  Japan |        3       |     300    |    A    |
+-----+--------+----------------+------------+---------+
|  5  |  Japan |        3       |     350    |    B    |
+-----+--------+----------------+------------+---------+
|  6  | Mexico |        1       |     200    |    A    |
+-----+--------+----------------+------------+---------+
```

The individual data now needs to be checked against the requirements set in another sheet:

```
+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------+
| Requirement | MinHorsepower | MaxHorsepower | License |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------+
| 1           | 200           | 250           | A       |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------+
| 2           | 250           | 500           | B       |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------+
| 3           | 250           | 400           | A       |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------+
```

In order to relate back to my present situation, I am only looking at either the Monaco, Japan or Mexico Race, and there is only 1 record in the requirements sheet, where the value in e.g. Cell B2 is always the MinHorsepower and the value in C2 is always the MaxHorsepower. So these cells are a named range that I can access in my data sheet.

Now however I would like to obtain all races at once, and refer conditional formatting formulas to the particular requirement.

Focussing on "Horsepower" in Monaco (requirement set 2), I can now find out that the min Horsepower is 250 and the max is 500 - so I will colour that column for car 1 as red and for car 2 as green.
The formula is programatically copied from the header row (the first conditional format rule is `if row(D1) = 1 then do nothing`)

I can't decide what the best approach to the problem is. Ideally, the formula is readable, something like `AND(D2 >= MinHorsepower; D2 <= MaxHorsepower) - I cannot imagine it to be maintainable if I had to use Vlookup combined with Indirect and Match to match a column header in requirements for that particular requirement - especially when it comes to combining criteria like in the HP example with min and max above.

I am wondering if I should read the requirements table into a dictionary or something in VBA, and then use a function like

```
public function check(requirementId as int, requirement$)
```

which then in Excel I could use like `=D2 >= check(c2, "MinHorsepower")`

Playing around with this a little bit it appears to be pretty slow as opposed to the previous system where I could only have one requirement. It would be fantastic if you could help me out with a fresh approach to this problem. I'll update this question as I go along; I'm not sure if I managed to illustrate the example really well but the actual data wouldn't mean anything to you.
In any case, thanks for hanging in until here!

**Edit 29 October 2016**

[I have found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180646/excel-vba-nested-dictionary-accessing-items) as basis for mine. Using the following code I can add my whole requirements table to a dictionary, and access the requirement.

Using a class clsRangeToDictionary (based on Tim Williams clsMatrix)

```
Option Explicit

Private m_array As Variant
Private dictRows As Object
Private dictColumns As Object

Public Sub Init(vArray As Variant)
    Dim i As Long
    Set dictRows = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictColumns = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'add the row keys and positions. Skip the first row as it contains the column key
    For i = LBound(vArray, 1) + 1 To UBound(vArray, 1)
        dictRows.Add vArray(i, 1), i
    Next i
    'add the column keys and positions, skipping the first column
    For i = LBound(vArray, 2) + 1 To UBound(vArray, 2)
        dictColumns.Add vArray(1, i), i
    Next i
    ' store the array for future use
    m_array = vArray
End Sub

Public Function GetValue(rowKey, colKey) As Variant
    If dictRows.Exists(rowKey) And dictColumns.Exists(colKey) Then
        GetValue = m_array(dictRows(rowKey), dictColumns(colKey))
    Else
        Err.Raise 1000, "clsRangeToDictionary:GetValue", "The requested row key " & CStr(rowKey) & " or column Key " & CStr(colKey) & " does not exist"
    End If
End Function

'   return a zero-based array of RowKeys
Public Function RowKeys() As Variant
    RowKeys = dictRows.Keys
End Function
'   return a zero-based array of ColumnKeys
Public Function ColumnKeys() As Variant
    ColumnKeys = dictColumns.Keys
End Function
```

I can now read the whole RequirementSet table into a dictionary and write a helper to obtain the particular requirement roughly so:

```
myDictionaryObject.GetValue(table1's RequirementSet, "MinHorsePower")
```

If someone could help me figure out how to put this into an answer giving the credit due to Tim Williams that'd be great.

Comment: As I understand it, table 1 is loaded from the database. I do not understand "RequirementSet". Has this come from the database? A driver for Car 1 must have a type A licence. So Requirement 1 looks more appropriate than requirement 2. I think you need to concentrate on how to decide which requirement (or requirements?) apply to which database row. Until you know the complexity of the requirement applying process, you cannot decide the best approach to implementing that process.

Comment: I find conditional formatting useful when the user is entering data.  As I understand it, you load table 1 from a database, run a macro to check the data against requirements then review the results of that check.  Why not just colour the cells?  Why is the macro generating formulae for Excel to obey when it has already decided what colour or other format is required?

Comment: This site is for programming questions not design questions.  I do not know where this question should be posted but please do not be surprised if it is moved or closed as inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your response; it really is a development question however I don't yet know what to develop...
In response: Table 1 is loaded from the database and every record carries the information of its requirement set to be used.
The driver in car 1 _has_ an A license, but requirementset 2 (which it is) demands a B license. Therefore in the example it would be displayed as red (bad) instead of green (ok).

Comment: Look at other questions?  “I am trying to achieve Effect X with these statements but I get Effect Y” is typical.  Questions like “Here is my problem? What should I do?” get voted down and closed. You have clearly put effort into understanding and describing your problem which may save your question.  I confess that I like design questions but I appear to be in a minority.

Comment: In your Table 2, requirements are identified by sequential numbers.  Does this match reality?  A dictionary would be useful if requirements were identified by unique, discontinuous keys. An array would be better with sequential or nearly sequential numbers.

Comment: If requirements are numbered 1, 2, 3, etc. I would load Table 2 (`Variant = Range.Value`) to an array.  I would run down Table 1, checking conditions and colouring rows as appropriate.  If the user wants a reason, I would consider recording a comment in column A.

Comment: If requirement ids are discontinuous, I would sort both worksheets by requirement id and then work down the two tables matching on requirement id.  If I could not sort the worksheets or if I was worried about the time to physically re-sequence 71 column rows, I would load them to arrays and use an indexed sort. I would then use the indices to work down the two tables matching on requirement id.

Comment: The only difference between present and f(u|ea)ture is that I presently check against a fixed set of requirements. So if table 2's header in column B is "MinHorsepower", then B2 (which contains the value) is the named Range MinHorsepower. The added complexity is when obtaining more than 1 such requirement row. Now I would need to match the data's (table 1) requirement set id to the corresponding set first, then matching the required value for comparison with the actual data.
I'll look at your suggestion with loading the table 2 now and update my question accordingly. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: I have [found my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180646/excel-vba-nested-dictionary-accessing-items). I would like to give [Tim Williams](http://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) credit but don't know if that is possible? I wouldn't necessarily like to answer my own question using his knowledge.

Comment: You can vote up Tim's answer by clicking the upward facing triangle at the top. That is worth 10 points on his reputation. I suspect that most of the time knowing our efforts are helpful and appreciated is more important that the points. If you include @ followed by his name in a comment, he will be get a message in his Inbox telling him to read the comment.

Comment: I've already voted it up, thanks. Should I vote to close mine? Add an answer mentioning the original solution?
@tim-williams Not sure you see this comment unless you've been involved in the thread, but if you do, thanks! If you reply I'll happily accept it as the answer.