# VBA Multi-dimension array with keys?

Tags: vba, data-structures, outlook

How do I make arrays like as show below in VBA? Every other language it is fairly straight forward. I cannot figure out the best way to design the code. I have looked into collections and it might work, except that I need to create a new collection on another collection dynamically. Which is not possible.

```
 contacts => array(
    'company1' => array(
        'POMain' => array(
        [0] = array(
            'Email' => 'demo@demo.com',
            'Name' => 'John Doe'
        ),
        [1] = array(
            'Email' => 'demo@demo.com',
            'Name' => 'John Doe'
        )
        ),
        'POCC' => array(
            'Email' => 'demo@demo.com',
            'Name' => 'John Doe'
        )
    ),
    'company2' => array(
        etcetera...
    )
)
```

Comment: My first thought would be to look into dictionaries. I believe you can house dictionaries within other dictionaries. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27180646/10361731)

Comment: So a `Collection` of arrays? A jagged array? A `Dictionary` of arrays? A `Dictionary` of `Collection`? Some mix of those?  Lots of ways you can take this...  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Comintern It needs to be dynamic. It seems like with collections everything has to be re dimmed every time I want to add a new value. I want to be able to add an unknown amount of contacts that are arrays. This is the exact structure I am showing in my initial comment.

Comment: Huh? That's the point of using a container *object*. You only have to resize *arrays*. Tony's answer demonstrates that fairly effectively.

Comment: @MrPlow254 seems you are conflating `Collection` and *array*, which are two wildly different data structures. You don't "re-dim" a collection.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you for clearing that up. Is it possible to set a key from a variable, and then add a collection to that key? Example an object company.name assigned as a collection key value. Then later call that key and add another item to it. It seems like that is not possible with Set somename = New Collection. How do you define a dynamic key and that will create a new array within. Example in php to do this is just $array[$dynamickey][] = array('someotherkey' => 2); and it will add a new array within it.

Comment: PHP also merrily lets you stringify identifiers, I wouldn't use it as a reference for anything whatsoever. Read Tony's answer. Carefully.

Comment: TBH, it looks like what you *really* need is an OOP solution with `Company` and `Contact` classes.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Comintern, there are many different approaches to creating a VBA data structure that would meet your stated requirement.  Without more information, it is difficult or impossible to know which is the best approach for you.

You appear to think that you cannot have a collection within a collection.  This is incorrect.  Below I demonstrate an approach which holds collections within a collection.  However, this is not an approach I would use except for a one-off exercise.  I would not like to be the maintenance programmer asked to update this approach unless it was fully documented.

I needed some test data to demonstrate my code.  I decided to use Excel but this approach would work with any Office product that could hold data of this nature.  My data was:

[image]

I found loading the data structure quite easy with this data.  I believe the documentation within the macro is adequate.

Extracting values from the data structure was much harder because there are so many levels.  I have used constants to make the code a little less difficult to read.  The components of the data structure are:

- `Contacts`: A collection
- `Contacts.Count`: The number of elements in `Contacts`
- `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)`: One element from `Contacts`
- `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctCompN)`: The company name for `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)`
- `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctPrsnMain)`: The collection of main persons for      `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)`
- `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctPrsnCC)`: The collection of CC persons for    `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)`
- `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctPrsnMain).Count`: The number of elements in the collection of Main persons for `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)`
- `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctPrsnCC).Count`: The number of elements in the collection of CC persons for `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)`
- `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctPrsnMain)(InxPrsnMainCrnt)`: One element from the collection of Main persons for `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)`
- `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctPrsnCC)(InxPrsnCCCrnt)`: One element from the collection of CC persons for `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)`
- `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctPrsnMain)(InxPrsnMainCrnt)(InxPrsnN)`: The person name from one element from the collection of Main persons for `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)`
- `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctPrsnMain)(InxPrsnMainCrnt)(InxPrsnA)`: The email address from one element from the collection of Main persons for `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)`
- `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctPrsnCC)(InxPrsnCCCrnt)(InxPrsnN)`: The person name from one element from the collection of CC persons for `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)`
- `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctPrsnCC)(InxPrsnCCCrnt)(InxPrsnA)`: The email address from one element from the collection of CC persons for `Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)`

My code is:

```
Option Explicit

  ' Columns within worksheet
  Const ColNameC As Long = 1
  Const ColTypeP As Long = 2
  Const ColNameP As Long = 3
  Const ColAddrP As Long = 4
  ' First data within worksheet
  Const RowDataFirst As Long = 3

Sub Demo()

  Dim CompanyNameCrnt As String
  Dim Contacts As New Collection
  ' Each entry in Contacts is a zero-based array containing
  '  * String company name
  '  * Collection of main persons. Each entry in this collection
  '    is a zero-based array containing a person name and a person email
  '    address.
  '  * Collection of cc persons. Format same as collection of main persons
  Dim PersonsMainCrnt As Collection
  Dim PersonsCCCrnt As Collection
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim TypeCrnt As String

  CompanyNameCrnt = ""   ' No pending company

  With Worksheets("Contacts")

    RowCrnt = RowDataFirst

    Do While .Cells(RowCrnt, ColNameP).Value <> ""

      If .Cells(RowCrnt, ColNameC).Value <> "" Then
        ' Start of new company
        If CompanyNameCrnt <> "" Then
          ' Output company just finished
          Contacts.Add VBA.Array(CompanyNameCrnt, _
                                 PersonsMainCrnt, _
                                 PersonsCCCrnt)
        End If
        ' Prepare for new company
        CompanyNameCrnt = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColNameC).Value
        Set PersonsMainCrnt = New Collection
        Set PersonsCCCrnt = New Collection
      End If
      If .Cells(RowCrnt, ColTypeP).Value <> "" Then
        ' New type of person
        TypeCrnt = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColTypeP).Value
      End If
      If TypeCrnt = "Main" Then
        PersonsMainCrnt.Add VBA.Array(.Cells(RowCrnt, ColNameP).Value, _
                                      .Cells(RowCrnt, ColAddrP).Value)
      ElseIf TypeCrnt = "CC" Then
        PersonsCCCrnt.Add VBA.Array(.Cells(RowCrnt, ColNameP).Value, _
                                    .Cells(RowCrnt, ColAddrP).Value)
      Else
        Debug.Assert False    ' Unknown type
      End If

      RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1

    Loop

    If CompanyNameCrnt <> "" Then
      ' Output final company
      Contacts.Add VBA.Array(CompanyNameCrnt, _
                             PersonsMainCrnt, _
                             PersonsCCCrnt)
    End If

  End With

  ' Indices into element of Contacts
  Const InxCntctCompN As Long = 0
  Const InxCntctPrsnMain As Long = 1
  Const InxCntctPrsnCC As Long = 2
  ' Indices into element of PersonsMain and PersonsCC
  Const InxPrsnN As Long = 0
  Const InxPrsnA As Long = 1

  Dim InxCntctCrnt As Long        ' Loop variable for Contacts
  Dim InxPrsnMainCrnt As Long     ' Loop variable for main persons
  Dim InxPrsnCCCrnt As Long       ' Loop variable for CC persons

  For InxCntctCrnt = 1 To Contacts.Count
    For InxPrsnMainCrnt = 1 To Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctPrsnMain).Count
      Debug.Print Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctCompN) & "|Main|" & _
                  Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctPrsnMain)(InxPrsnMainCrnt)(InxPrsnN) & "|" & _
                  Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctPrsnMain)(InxPrsnMainCrnt)(InxPrsnA)
    Next
    For InxPrsnCCCrnt = 1 To Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctPrsnCC).Count
      Debug.Print Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctCompN) & "| CC |" & _
                  Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctPrsnCC)(InxPrsnCCCrnt)(InxPrsnN) & "|" & _
                  Contacts(InxCntctCrnt)(InxCntctPrsnCC)(InxPrsnCCCrnt)(InxPrsnA)
    Next
  Next

End Sub
```

The output from this code:

```
Company1|Main|John Doe|DoeJohn@One.com
Company1|Main|Jane Doe|DoeJane@One.com
Company1| CC |John Brown|BrownJohn@One.com
Company1| CC |Jane Brown|BrownJane@One.com
Company1| CC |Chris Green|GreenChris@One.com
Company2|Main|Donald Black|DonaldBlack@Two.com
Company2|Main|Esther Clark|EstherClark@Two.com
Company2|Main|Francis Davis|FrancisDavis@Two.com
Company2| CC |George Eton|GeorgeEton@Two.com
Company2| CC |Harry Fox|HarryFox@Two.com
Company3|Main|Iris Grant|GrantIris@Three.com
Company3|Main|John Hammond|HammondJohn@Three.com
Company3|Main|Keith Island|IslandKeith@Three.com
```

Without knowing more about your objectives, I cannot be sure of the approach I would recommend.  My preferred approach would be user types within a collection. Unfortunately, user types are not allowed within collections.  You can have classes within a collection but classes have different restrictions which limits their usefulness.  I suspect user types within an array would be the most self-documenting approach.  I can provide a demonstration of that approach if you think it might be helpful.

Comment: I'm pulling all the information from the mycontacts database in outlook. I have two custom columns "POMain", and "POcc" with true/false as their values. The VBA code will search all contacts and add them to the correct array designation if the contact is a POMain=true, or POcc=true. It will be created dynamically with an unknown dim value. That is issue one I have had with collections, needing to know the size of the array before I make the array.  Issue two is that the value types are not supported it seems like. The code you just provided might work with some tweaking.

Comment: This is the most thorough answer to a vague question I've seen in quite a while. Kudos!

Comment: @MrPlow254 then _don't use arrays_! You'll note that there isn't a single array in this example, and it's that way for a reason.

Comment: @FreeMan sorry there is a computer language barrier. When I refer to an array I am speaking from a PHP perspective. An array in PHP is a map with key and value with multidimensional abilities. Don't get hung up on the word array. I made it clear in my initial comment that I have an array structure that I want to create dynamically. I am not familiar with VBA and its not straight forward like lua, php, java etc.

Comment: @MrPlow254 You aren't really referring to an array in PHP *either* then. What you're talking about is an [*associative array*](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-php-3rd/9781449361068/ch05s01.html). The reason the linked article makes a distinction between the 2 is that the generally accepted definition of a vanilla "array" is indexed. Which everyone here is referring to. In VBA, an associative array is a `Collection` or a `Dictionary` or something else that you provide a custom implementation for.

Comment: @Comintern you are correct. I am in the process of implementing a dictionary. Collections have not worked so far which is why I even created this question.

Comment: @MrPlow254 Why don't you dump the data to a text file and then process it in a language you already know?

Comment: @MrPlow254 If you need to create and process the structure in VBA, please give more information about the processing.

Comment: @MrPlow254 Let's try and get past the language barrier by explaining some VBA terms.  Arrays can be fixed size or dynamic.  Dynamic arrays can be resized at anytime with existing content preserved although only the last dimension can be changed.   Arrays are typed: String, Integer, Long, Double, Boolean and so on. One available type is Variant which effectly means untyped since a Variant can hold values of any type including an array.

Comment: @MrPlow254 An element of a collection can, optionally, have a key. An element of a collection can be accessed by its position and, if it has one, its key. New elements can be added at the end or before or after any existing element. Any existing element can be deleted. A collection grows or shrinks as necessary with available memory being the only limit. Collection elements are untyped.

Comment: @MrPlow254 In one of your comments you say the required value types are not supported.  What type do you need that is not supported?